# Main prints nulls and 0; instead of the correct names; due to array/list issue

Tags: java, arrays, list, printing

```
Last Block of main prints:
null, 0, null 
null, 0, null
null, 0, null
null, 0, null
But should print the following: Ferrari 488, 0, Ferrari; Audi A7, 0, Audi
Ferrari F1, 20, Ferrari; AudiR8, 3, Audi
```

Tried changing the array list type to String which was mentioned as error.
Tried Several list types. But i dont get a specified output, only output of 0/null and I have been trying a lot of things; hope anyone can help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Car {
    String name;
    String type;
    int age;

    Car() {
        name = null;
        type = null;
        age = 0;
    }

    Car(String name, String type, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // GETTERS:
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    // SETTER:
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println(name + ", " + age + ", " + type);
    }
}
```

```
class Audi extends Car {
    String type = "Audi";

    Audi() {
        super("Audi A7", "Audi", 0);
    }

    Audi(String name, int age) {
        super(name, "Audi", age);
    }
}
```

```
class Ferrari extends Car {
    String type = "Ferrari";

    Ferrari() {
        super("Ferrari 488", "Ferrari", 0);
    }

    Ferrari(String name, int age) {
        super(name, "Ferrari", age);
    }
}
```

```
class Mercedes extends Car {
    String type = "Mercedes";

    Mercedes() {
        super("AMGGT", "Mercedes", 0);
    }

    Mercedes(String name, int age) {
        super(name, "Mercedes", age);
    }
}
```

```
class Dealer {
    // ArrayList for Cars
    private ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCar(Car a) {
        cars.add(a);
    }

    public void printAllInfo() {

        Car print = new Car();
        print.printInfo();

        for (Car a : cars) {
            print.printInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class CarBuilder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ferrari e1 = null, e2 = null;
        Audi p1 = null, p2 = null;
        Dealer z = null;

        try {
            e1 = new Ferrari();
            if (e1.name.equals("Ferrari 488")) {
                System.out.println("PASS1");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL1");
            }
            if (e1.type.equals("Ferrari")) {
                System.out.println("PASS2");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL2");
            }
            if (e1.age == 0) {
                System.out.println("PASS3");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL3");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL-block1");
        }

        try {
            p1 = new Audi();
            if (p1.name.equals("Audi A7")) {
                System.out.println("PASS4");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL4");
            }
            if (p1.type.equals("Audi")) {
                System.out.println("PASS5");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL5");
            }
            if (p1.age == 0) {
                System.out.println("PASS6");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL6");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL-block2");
        }

        try {
            e2 = new Ferrari("Ferrari F1", 20);
            if (e2.name.equals("Ferrari F1")) {
                System.out.println("PASS7");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL7");
            }
            if (e2.type.equals("Ferrari")) {
                System.out.println("PASS8");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL8");
            }
            if (e2.age == 20) {
                System.out.println("PASS9");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL9");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL-block3");
        }

        try {
            p2 = new Audi("AudiR8", 3);
            if (p2.name.equals("AudiR8")) {
                System.out.println("PASS10");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL10");
            }
            if (p2.type.equals("Audi")) {
                System.out.println("PASS11");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL11");
            }
            if (p2.age == 3) {
                System.out.println("PASS12");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL12");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL-block4");
        }

        System.out.println("--- Testing printInfo function ---");
        try {
            e1.printInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL-print1");
        }
        try {
            p1.printInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL-print2");
        }
        try {
            e2.printInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL-print3");
        }
        try {
            p2.printInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL-print4");
        }

        System.out.println("--- Testing printAll function. Should match the above output ---");
        try {
            z = new Dealer();
            z.addCar((Car) e1);
            z.addCar((Car) p1);
            z.addCar((Car) e2);
            z.addCar((Car) p2);
            z.printAllInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL-lastblock1");
            System.out.println("FAIL-lastblock2");
            System.out.println("FAIL-lastblock3");
            System.out.println("FAIL-lastblock4");
        }
    }
}
```

should print: Ferrari 488, 0, Ferrari
instead of null, 0, null

Comment: You want us to take the time to understand your question and provide an answer, but first you should take the time to post well-formatted code. Why make your code harder to read and understand than is necessary?

Comment: Code is actually two files CarBuilder (from Carbuilder class onwards) and Dealer.

Comment: Again, please format it well.

Comment: Sorry about that; understand it is a lot of code and i was trying to shorten it but i thought it would make things very complicated. The code works except for the output of the last block in main.

Comment: It's not the length, it's the formatting. I've formatted your code for you this time, but again it is your question, and so in the future, the effort to do this should be yours (if you want a decent answer).

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was figuring out what would make sense; but your formatting looks a lot better; Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Your Dealer class code is only printing the null-filled car:

```
public void printAllInfo() {

    Car print = new Car();  // null-filled Car
    print.printInfo();

    for (Car a : cars) {
        print.printInfo();  // !!!!! HERE !!!!
    }
}
```

At the indicated line, you're not printing `a`'s data but rather the null-filled print's data.

Instead, it should be:

```
public void printAllInfo() {

    // ** No real need for these lines:
    // Car print = new Car();
    // print.printInfo();

    for (Car a : cars) { 
        // print.printInfo();
        a.printInfo();   // *** note the change? ***
    }
}
```

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels; THANK YOU!!!!! I was looking in the wrong area for hours and couldn't figure this out. Compiled it with the new code and it works.
Thanks so much!

Comment: @PBody123: you're welcome. A useful reference is [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and you'll want to read it fully.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the useful info. Very happy about your help Hovercraft Full Of Eels!!